# PhantomJS does not work

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

I'm using PhantomJS to get some datas from WebSites and as a sample for my goal, I've made this:

```
var page=require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.phantomjs.org',function() {
    var my_data=page.evaluate(function() {
        var my_data=document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerText;
        return my_data;
    });
    console.log(my_data);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But this code is not working. Command prompt prints out only 'null'. What have I missed at here?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `page.evaluate` is async function. So `console.log(my_data)` is executed before `page.evaluate` finish, that's why you got `null`.

It is supposed to be

```
var page=require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.phantomjs.org',function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var my_data=document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerText;
        console.log(my_data);        
        phantom.exit();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work too and in addition any my attemptions are failed.